# Wrong transformations in unity standalone player build

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am developing a native (c++) plugin (windows only for now) for unity (2018.1.0f2).
The plugin downloads textures and meshes and provides them to the unity.
There is a LOT of boilerplate code that I would like to spare you of.
Anyway, the rendering is done like this:

```cs
void RegenerateCommandBuffer(CommandBuffer buffer, List<DrawTask> tasks)
{
    buffer.Clear();
    buffer.SetProjectionMatrix(cam.projectionMatrix); // protected Camera cam; cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
    foreach (DrawTask t in tasks)
    {
        if (t.mesh == null)
            continue;
        MaterialPropertyBlock mat = new MaterialPropertyBlock();
        bool monochromatic = false;
        if (t.texColor != null)
        {
            var tt = t.texColor as VtsTexture;
            mat.SetTexture(shaderPropertyMainTex, tt.Get());
            monochromatic = tt.monochromatic;
        }
        if (t.texMask != null)
        {
            var tt = t.texMask as VtsTexture;
            mat.SetTexture(shaderPropertyMaskTex, tt.Get());
        }
        mat.SetMatrix(shaderPropertyUvMat, VtsUtil.V2U33(t.data.uvm));
        mat.SetVector(shaderPropertyUvClip, VtsUtil.V2U4(t.data.uvClip));
        mat.SetVector(shaderPropertyColor, VtsUtil.V2U4(t.data.color));
        // flags: mask, monochromatic, flat shading, uv source
        mat.SetVector(shaderPropertyFlags, new Vector4(t.texMask == null ? 0 : 1, monochromatic ? 1 : 0, 0, t.data.externalUv ? 1 : 0));
        buffer.DrawMesh((t.mesh as VtsMesh).Get(), VtsUtil.V2U44(t.data.mv), material, 0, -1, mat);
    }
}
```

There are two control modes. Either the unity camera is controlled by the camera in the plugin, or the plugin camera is controlled by the unity camera. In my current scenario, the plugin camera is controlled by the unity camera. There is no special magic behind the scenes, but some of the transformations needs to be done in double precision to work without meshes 'jumping' around.

```cs
void CamOverrideView(ref double[] values)
{
    Matrix4x4 Mu = mapTrans.localToWorldMatrix * VtsUtil.UnityToVtsMatrix;
    // view matrix
    if (controlTransformation == VtsDataControl.Vts)
        cam.worldToCameraMatrix = VtsUtil.V2U44(Math.Mul44x44(values, Math.Inverse44(VtsUtil.U2V44(Mu))));
    else
        values = Math.Mul44x44(VtsUtil.U2V44(cam.worldToCameraMatrix), VtsUtil.U2V44(Mu));
}

void CamOverrideParameters(ref double fov, ref double aspect, ref double near, ref double far)
{
    // fov
    if (controlFov == VtsDataControl.Vts)
        cam.fieldOfView = (float)fov;
    else
        fov = cam.fieldOfView;
    // near & far
    if (controlNearFar == VtsDataControl.Vts)
    {
        cam.nearClipPlane = (float)near;
        cam.farClipPlane = (float)far;
    }
    else
    {
        near = cam.nearClipPlane;
        far = cam.farClipPlane;
    }
}
```

And a shader:

```c
Shader "Vts/UnlitShader"
{
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" }
        LOD 100

        Pass
        {
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct vIn
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uvInternal : TEXCOORD0;
                float2 uvExternal : TEXCOORD1;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                float2 uvTex : TEXCOORD0;
                float2 uvClip : TEXCOORD1;
            };

            struct fOut
            {
                float4 color : SV_Target;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            sampler2D _MaskTex;

            float4x4 _UvMat;
            float4 _UvClip;
            float4 _Color;
            float4 _Flags; // mask, monochromatic, flat shading, uv source

            v2f vert (vIn i)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(i.vertex);
                o.uvTex = mul((float3x3)_UvMat, float3(_Flags.w > 0 ? i.uvExternal : i.uvInternal, 1.0)).xy;
                o.uvClip = i.uvExternal;
                return o;
            }

            fOut frag (v2f i)
            {
                fOut o;

                // texture color
                o.color = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uvTex);
                if (_Flags.y > 0)
                    o.color = o.color.rrra; // monochromatic texture

                // uv clipping
                if (   i.uvClip.x < _UvClip.x
                    || i.uvClip.y < _UvClip.y
                    || i.uvClip.x > _UvClip.z
                    || i.uvClip.y > _UvClip.w)
                    discard;

                // mask
                if (_Flags.x > 0)
                {
                    if (tex2D(_MaskTex, i.uvTex).r < 0.5)
                        discard;
                }

                // uniform tint
                o.color *= _Color;

                return o;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

It all works perfectly - in editor. It also works well in standalone DEVELOPMENT build. But the transformations get wrong when in 'deploy' builds. The rendered parts look as if they were rotated around wrong axes or with different polarities.

Can you spot some obvious mistakes?

My first suspect was OpenGL vs DirectX differences, but the 'deploy' and 'development' builds should use the same, should they not? Moreover, I have tried changing the player setting to force one or the other, but without any differences.

Edit:

Good image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RTlVZBSAj7LIml1sBCX7nYTvMNaN0xK-

Bad image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=176ahft7En6MqT-aS2RdKXOVW68NmvK2L

Note how the terrain is correctly aligned with the atmosphere.

Steps to reproduce

1) Create a new project in unity

2) Download the assets https://drive.google.com/open?id=18uKuiya5XycjGWEcsF-xjy0fn7sf-D82 and extract them into the newly created project

3) Try it in editor -> should work ok (it will start downloading meshes and textures from us, so be patient; the downloaded resources are cached in eg. C://users//.cache/vts-browser)
The plane is controlled by mouse with LMB pressed.

4) Build in development build and run -> should work ok too

5) Build NOT in development build and run -> the terrain transformations behave incorrectly.

Furthermore, I have published the repository. Here is the unity-specific code: https://github.com/Melown/vts-browser-unity-plugin
Unfortunately, I did not intend to publish it this soon, so the repository is missing some formal things like readme and build instructions. Most information can, however, be found in the submodules.

Comment: Hi dear friend we're here to solving your problem but It's better to ask short.can you add Image to your question that describe problem?

Comment: when I use your code I have many compiler errors!!

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamali indeed it is not meant to be self-contained, as I said, there is a LOT more.

Comment: the important point is that it works in development build but not deploy build.

Comment: please upload demo project for testing purposes

Comment: @SeyedMortezaKamali I have updated the question with images and a demo.

Comment: I download your project but unfortunately I got confused Your question needs to be discussed.you can ask this question on unity [https://forum.unity.com](https://forum.unity.com).but always try to ask short question.you can separate your question to small question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CommandBuffer.SetProjectionMatrix apparently needs a matrix that has been adjusted by GL.GetGPUProjectionMatrix.

```
buffer.SetProjectionMatrix(GL.GetGPUProjectionMatrix(cam.projectionMatrix, false));
```

Unfortunately, I still do not understand why would this cause a different behavior between deploy and development builds. I would have expected it to only make difference on different platforms.